# strange asp.net dropdownlist selecte value not set

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the following code to populate my drop down list:

```
if (ddl_year.Items.Count == 0)
{
    int current_year = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem((current_year - i).ToString(), 
                (current_year - i).ToString());

        ddl_year.Items.Add(li);
    }

    ddl_year.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

then later, I use i set the selected value as follow:

```
ddl_year.SelectedValue="2010";
```

The selected value remains `2012`;  Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?
The strange thing is that i do exactly the same thing for an other drop down list which get a selected value of `2009` and that value is shown correctly.

Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

More details about the actual program:

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{

      FillYears(ddl_year_B); // The content of this method is what i desribed ealier in my post.
      FillYears(ddl_year_A);

      if (Session[CurrentCompareYearWithSessionKey] == null)
            Session[CurrentCompareYearWithSessionKey] = Monitor_year - 1;

      ddl_year_B.SelectedValue = Session[CurrentCompareYearWithSessionKey].ToString();//Works as expected

      if (Session[CurrentSelectedYearSessionKey] == null)
            Session[CurrentSelectedYearSessionKey] = Monitor_year;

      ddl_year_A.SelectedValue = Session[CurrentSelectedYearSessionKey].ToString();// Does not work as expected
}
```

And below the aspx markup:

```
<td > Year:</td>
                    <td >
                        <asp:DropDownList  ID="ddl_year_A" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_year_A_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td >Compared year:</td>
                    <td >
                        <asp:DropDownList Width="80px" ID="ddl_year_B" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_year_B_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
```

Comment: instead of setting `SselectedValue` set `SelectedIndex` property .

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi SelectedIndex is not what is needed, because he is trying to select the needed item based on its value, not its position in the item list. @ Meelfan: The population of the dropdownlist seems correct, could you add a code snippet of the part where you try to set the SelectedValue property? (Specifically: Are you setting the SelectedValue after a postback? Is the dropdownlist part of the .aspx page, or do you create this control dynamically in code-behind?)

Comment: are you getting an exception or anything when you try and select the value? are you trying to select before or after you populate the list?  does this happen in postback? we need some more info to try and help.

Comment: If you are witnessing this issue only after a postback, write the code for populating the dropdown list inside `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`. This will prevent the dropdown from being bound on subsequent postbacks.

Comment: No exception and no, i'm not setting this after postBack. I will update the question with the actual code

Comment: does `Session[CurrentSelectedYearSessionKey]` is set? what is value for `Monitor_year`. Can you also post entire method `FillYear` (with header)

Comment: It is a mistery to me why "B" works but not "A".

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp Does your dropdown has `autopostBack ="True"` ?

Comment: yes as updated in my post.

Comment: are `SelectedIndexChanged` event handlers identical? what do they do?

Comment: they just equally reload the data source of a gridView to reflect the year selection. Nothing fancy. And it works all the way. The problem is only the first selected value of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case your code is working fine as expected. Pl. tell what is the initial value of Monitor_year ?

I reconstructed your code as follows and it is working perfactly:

```
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                int Monitor_year = 2010;

                FillYears(ddl_year_B); // The content of this method is what i desribed ealier in my post.
                FillYears(ddl_year_A);

                if (Session["CurrentCompareYearWithSessionKey"] == null)
                    Session["CurrentCompareYearWithSessionKey"] = Monitor_year - 1;

                ddl_year_B.SelectedValue = Session["CurrentCompareYearWithSessionKey"].ToString();//Works as expected

                if (Session["CurrentSelectedYearSessionKey"] == null)
                    Session["CurrentSelectedYearSessionKey"] = Monitor_year;

                ddl_year_A.SelectedValue = Session["CurrentSelectedYearSessionKey"].ToString();// Does not work as expected
            }



//-----------

        protected void FillYears(DropDownList ddl_year)
        {
            if (ddl_year.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                int current_year = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    ListItem li = new ListItem((current_year - i).ToString(), (current_year - i).ToString());

                    ddl_year.Items.Add(li);
                }

                ddl_year.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

//---------------------  aspx page

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_year_B" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_year_A" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

The value of ddl_year_B and ddl_year_A is 2009 and 2010 respectively
```

Comment: I isolated the code like in your example and the bug strangely disappeared. many thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks, I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , it totally work for me .

```
    int yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
            for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
            {
                ddlYear.Items.Add(new ListItem((yr - y).ToString()));
            }
    ddlYear.SelectedValue = "2010";
```

Answer (score -1):

`SelectedValue` property of drop down list only returns currently selected value. Which means you can't set any value for this property.(get property only works).try this

```
ListItem selectedListItem = ddl.Items.FindByValue("2010");

if (selectedListItem != null)
{
    selectedListItem.Selected = true;
};
```

Comment: "SelectedValue property of drop down list only returns currently selected value" is wrong: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: exactly. sorry for any inconvenience